# Pig Date Formatting Issues

Tags: apache-pig

Input format of the file = 000018|187878|2005-09-31 10:20:35|.
I want to generate the output in Pig as 000018|187878|2005/09/31 10:20:35|. How do I get this done in Pig?

Answer (score 0):

Write a UDF naming DateFormat, and apply it to your date field

Comment: I tried this. REPLACE(SUBSTRING(date,0,10),'-','/'). It worked.